# How do I verify a signature using DSA and my own "y" value in Python?

Tags: cryptography, pycrypto

I have to verify a signature using DSA FIPS 186-2 (I know it is not used anymore, but I need to make it work for a legacy system). My problem is I have the "y" DSA value, but I cannot work out how I can feed that into the Python code to create my own public key from the "y" value and then apply the verify.

For example below is what I have, but instead of generating a NEW key, I need to use my existing value?

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature

private_key = dsa.generate_private_key(
     key_size=1024,
     backend=default_backend()
)
data = b"this is some data I'd like to sign"
signature = private_key.sign(
     data,
     hashes.SHA1()
)

public_key = private_key.public_key()

try:
    public_key.verify(
             signature,
             data,
             hashes.SHA1())
except InvalidSignature:
    print ("Invalid")
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DSAPublicKey` instance can be created from a `DSAPublicNumbers` instance, which can be created using the raw values:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.dsa import DSAParameterNumbers, DSAPublicNumbers

param = DSAParameterNumbers(p, q, g)
pnum = DSAPublicNumbers(y, param)

pubkey = pnum.public_key(backend=default_backend())
```

Note that in addition to the `y` value, you will need the DSA parameters `p`, `q` and `g`.

Comment: Torin thank you very much. This is what I was looking for.